PermissionSetTabSetting object - how to update the visibilities
Is it possible at all without md api?
retrieved it successfuly but there is a need to change some visibilities in loop
my code
 List<PermissionSetTabSetting> tabs2GetUpserted = new List<PermissionSetTabSetting>();
    Map<String, String> existingTabsMap = new Map<String, String>();
    MetadataService.PermissionSet target = (MetadataService.PermissionSet) service.readMetadata('PermissionSet', new String[] { sourceName }).getRecords()[0];
    if(target.tabSettings != null) {                
        for(MetadataService.PermissionSetTabSetting tv: target.tabSettings ) { 
            existingTabsMap.put(tv.tab, (tv.visibility == 'Visible' ? 'DefaultOn' : 'DefaultOff'));
        }
    }
    for(string entry: this.source.keySet()) {
        string tempoVis = existingTabsMap?.get(entry);
        string vis = this.source.get(entry);
        PermissionSetTabSetting pst = new PermissionSetTabSetting();
        pst.parentId = currentTargetId;
        pst.name = entry;
        if(tempoVis == null) {
            pst.visibility = vis;
        } else {
            pst.visibility = 'DefaultOff';
        }
        tabs2GetUpserted.add(pst);
    }
    upsert tabs2GetUpserted;

but everytime got an error like  System.DmlException: Upsert failed. First exception on row ; first error: DUPLICATE_VALUE, Permission set already has a tab setting defined for tab . Update the existing tab setting.: []
what am i doing wrong?
or there is a need to use md api to upsert?
